# Show httpRequest.latency in gcloud logs tail

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm using `gcloud app logs tail` to show recent logs from App Engine.
However, I only get to see the request url and the response code.
How can I get more tags or labels, like 'response size', and 'latency'?

This is what I can see online in Logs Viewer.

[image: Online Log Viewer Screenshot]

And this is what I get from the commend.

[image: Command Line Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get the full request log data for App Engine Flex. This can be accomplished using the `gcloud logging read` command, which uses basic and advanced filters to return data from Cloud Logging.

To pull the full request logs, you might start with a command like this, and tune it to your purposes.

`watch -n 1 "gcloud logging read 'resource.type=\"gae_app\" AND logName=\"projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request\"' --limit=10 --format=json --freshness=1s"`

Note a few things about this example:

- Use `watch -n 1` to run the command every second, which is a workaround for the lack of `tail`. This is coupled with the `--freshness=1s` flag to get only fresh data each time.
- Be sure to change "YOUR_PROJECT_ID" to your project ID.
- Based on your screenshot, it appears you're trying to read the nginx.request logs from a Flex app; this example reflects that. If you want to read a different log type, you'll need to tune the log query in the command accordingly.

The documentation for configuring flags for `gcloud logging read` is [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read).

The documentation for composing basic and advanced filters is [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview).

Comment: It would appear that the gcloud app logs tail command is going forward in time (oldest to newest) , but the gcloud logging read command goes backwards, the latest log first then older ones. Which one of the two do you need? Gcloud logging read has the type of information that you need, although it should be filtered as I will warn you a lot of logs are being presented.

Comment: @Joshua Koh, I already visited the `logging read` option. But it's missing the `tail` option.  I need to watch it live on a dashboard.

Comment: Also, I don't necessarily want to get the 'whole' log. All I want is to specify another field in same line. (The same you can do online, where you can have any field added as a tag to show up on each line.)

Comment: The original message has been updated to add the `watch` command and `--freshness` flag to workaround the lack of a `tail` option and simulate `tail`-ing the logs.

Comment: I have created a feature request for your desired functionality for the gcloud app logs tail command. It is viewable here : 

issuetracker.google.com/157295083

Please remember though, this request might not be fulfilled, that means I am afraid that I cannot give you a timeline as to its completion.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, so this will probably be down voted, but to look at Response Sizes in Log Analytics, I've created below query...

```
SELECT
  http_request.request_method as method,
  http_request.request_url as url,
  AVG(http_request.response_size) as size,
FROM `<APP_NAME>.global._Default._Default`
where log_name = "projects/<APP_NAME>/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request" AND http_request.response_size IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY url, method
ORDER BY size DESC
```

Figure I'd share with the class...